# MIgrate Ubuntu to new hard drive?

Tags: ubuntu, backup-restoration, data-recovery

I lost a secondary hard drive in an Ubuntu Server this week. No problem restore data to the primary driver and one the way we go! Wouldn't that be nice if it was the end of the story!

I am later this week going to install a new hardware mirrored arrary into the server to prevent me from have to run out and replace the drive if something happens again. (yea I know should have been done a long time ago)

After I get the new array up and running what is the best way to I move the OS to the new array ? dd, dump, reinstall and reconfigure...

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/47707/moving-to-a-larger-drive-in-linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Kevin Kuphal - Linking to

[moving to a larger drive in linux](https://serverfault.com/questions/47707/moving-to-a-larger-drive-in-linux)

Answer (score 2):

Use rsync.

I would probably do something like:

rsync -av --exclude /new_drive / /new_drive

That should copy everything, then you'll need to edit your menu.lst in /boot/grub and also your fstab in /etc/fstab to point to the proper locations.